# Native function to get a special array for PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Every day , I have this pattern 
- an array of objects
- i make a loop to traverse the array

```
foreach($arr as $obj){
 $arrIds[]  = $obj->Id;
 $arrNames[] = $obj->Name;
 }
```

I could build a function like arrayFromProperties($Array,$ProperyName) but I was wondering if you know a native php function to do this, or something similar, without having to write a new class/function for this.

Comment: Once you write your own, you can use it everywhere ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you'll have to do this by your own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)?

Answer (score -1):

There isn't. It's not very hard to write, either. Feel free to reuse or adapt the following to your liking:

```
function soa_of_aos($aos) 
{
  $soa = array();
  foreach ($aos as $i => $struct)       
    foreach ($struct as $field => $value) 
      if (!isset($soa[$field])) $soa[$field] = array($i => $value);
      else $soa[$field][$i] = $value;
  return $soa;
}
```